# Webpack typescript compile without webpackJsonp

Tags: typescript, webpack

Is it possible to use webpack for packing without using webpack module loading?

I have an app that can use everything of webpack and next to this app I have a small typescript file `test.ts` that should be compiled, minified, etc. But the output  should be a simple js file that is not wrapped into `webpackJsonp`. Is is adding wayyyy too much overhead (96kb) for just a few lines that have no external dependency.

**test.ts**

```
alert('foo');
```

**test.js is**

```
webpackJsonp([1],{
/***/ 0:
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    __webpack_require__(1);
    __webpack_require__(75);
    module.exports = __webpack_require__(105);

/***/ },

/***/ 105:
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    "use strict";
    alert('test');

/***/ }
});
```

**test.js should**

```
alert('foo');
```

I try to keep one ecosystem (webpack) to build.

Comment: Could you provide us your webpack config? It looks like there's probably something in there that's causing the large amount of overhead you see.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I opened a bounty 'cause I'm having exactly the same issue.

Comment: Hey Sven-Michael Stübe - were you able to figure it out? I have the same requirement. I am looking for a standalone compilation without `webpackJsonp` to create a standalone HTML page with JS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not webpack overhead. This overhead caused by another reason. Here demonstration webpack configuration. The webpack build the bundle for source with content `alert()` with result size only 519 bytes instead of 96kb declared in question. The project content and result bundles (minified and non minified) are:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "webapp.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "ts-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^2.3.3",
    "webpack": "^2.5.1"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./public/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true
  }
}
```

**alert.ts**

```
alert(1);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Hello Workd!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="alert.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    App: './App',
    alert: './alert.ts',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, './public'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
  ]
}
```

**alert.js** - generated mininied

```
!function(n){function r(e){if(t[e])return t[e].exports;var o=t[e]={i:e,l:!1,exports:{}};return n[e].call(o.exports,o,o.exports,r),o.l=!0,o.exports}var t={};r.m=n,r.c=t,r.i=function(n){return n},r.d=function(n,t,e){r.o(n,t)||Object.defineProperty(n,t,{configurable:!1,enumerable:!0,get:e})},r.n=function(n){var t=n&&n.__esModule?function(){return n.default}:function(){return n};return r.d(t,"a",t),t},r.o=function(n,r){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(n,r)},r.p="",r(r.s=182)}({182:function(n,r){alert(1)}});
```

**alert.js** - generated non minified

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // identity function for calling harmony imports with the correct context
/******/    __webpack_require__.i = function(value) { return value; };
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, {
/******/                configurable: false,
/******/                enumerable: true,
/******/                get: getter
/******/            });
/******/        }
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = 182);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ({

/***/ 182:
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

alert(1);


/***/ })

/******/ });
```