# Independent custom webpack config without the webpackJsonp

Tags: angular, webpack

We have a standard Angular 8 app, but for some specific business-related reasons we need to have some on-the-side javascript functions exposed. In order to use one build and to be able to reuse code from the angular application, we use a [custom webpack config](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/custom-webpack) like this:

```
"customWebpackConfig": {
  "path": "./webpack.exposed.js",
  "replaceDuplicatePlugins": true,
  "mergeStrategies": {
    "module.rules": "append"
  }
}
```

The contents of the `webpack.exposed.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'for-others': './src/for-others/for-others.ts',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
  }
};
```

The `for-others` file contains just one exported function: `export default () => {'config1': 1, 'config2': 2};`

This works quite well and produces a separate `for-others.js` file. The problem is that this file doesn't just expose the function somehow, but adds something to a global `webpackJsonp` array. This means that other "external systems" can't use our config, as when this `push` is evaluated, we as a result we get a number (what the return type of `push` actually is).

```
(window["webpackJsonp"] = window["webpackJsonp"] || []).push([["for-others"],{
},[["./src/for-others/for-others.ts","runtime","vendor"]]]);
```

We've handled this requirement in another project where separate webpack builds are used. There the generated file is just:

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/ ...
/******/ })({<code>})
```

There we use a wrapper plugin that just adds `(() => {\nreturn` before this code and`\n})().default` after it, so the whole file evaluates to the default-ly exported function.

I've seen [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587074/webpack-typescript-compile-without-webpackjsonp) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34799181/how-to-generate-js-file-without-webpackjsonp) [already](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2281), but none actually provides a solution (or at least i can't get a solution out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can make use of [optimization.runtimeChunk](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationruntimechunk) webpack option.

By default Angular CLI sets it to ['single'](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/1db57d44ddc715fca3372a42b0ac09de0a28112c/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/browser.ts#L77) which is basically alias for:

```
optimization: {
  runtimeChunk: {
    name: 'runtime'
  }
}
```

So I would try something like:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'for-others': './src/for-others/for-others.ts',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: {
      name: entryPoint => entryPoint.name === 'for-others' ? 'for-others' : 'runtime'
    },
  }
};
```

This should remove `webpackJsonp` part. Then as you have already mentioned, you can use a wrapper plugin:

```
const WrapperPlugin = require('wrapper-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'for-others': './src/for-others/for-others.ts',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: {
      name: entryPoint => entryPoint.name === 'for-others' ? 'for-others' : 'runtime'
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new WrapperPlugin({
      test: /for-others\.js$/,
      header: '(() => {\nreturn ',
      footer: '\n})().default;'
    })
  ]
};
```

so that you can export whatever and wherever you want.

Comment: Looks promising, it really removes the `webpackJsonp` wrapper. But how can i access the default-ly exported function? For now webpack generates a code with roughly the following structure: `!function(e) { var t = {}; n.m = e, n.c = t, n.d = function(e, t, r) { ... }, ..., n(n.s = 'gjks'); }({ MPPj: function(e, t, n) {}, ... });`, which evaluates to `true`. Keep in mind i can still use the wrapper plugin to do some manipulations on the generated code.